# Create an anchor tag in a Underscore.js template

Tags: asp.net-core, underscore.js

I am trying to create an anchor tag inside an Underscore.js template and i need to set value of an attribute to Underscore variable:

```
_.each(items, function(item){%> 
    <a asp-route-id= "here i want to pass item.id but i can't"> 
         <%= itme.Name %>
    <a/>
%>}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use the same output tags, but inside the anchor `asp-route-id` attribute.

```
<a asp-route-id="<%= item.id %>"> 
     <%= item.Name %>
<a/>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, i thought i had tried that, so simple.